# Can't use jQuery to target elements in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a home-template.html file:

```
<template name="override-atPwdForm">
    <div id="test">Test 1</div
</template>
```

And home-template.js.

```
Template['override-atPwdForm'].onRendered = function(){
    $("#test").append("Test 2");
};
```

But when I reload the page, text 2 not be added in text 1.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below:

template code:

```
<template name="override-atPwdForm">
    <div id="test">Test 1</div>
</template>
```

JS code:

```
Template['override-atPwdForm'].onRendered(function() {
     Meteor.defer(function(){
         $("#test").append("Test 2");
     });
});
```

Here we are using `Meteor.defer` which is nothing but `setTimeout` of `0`.

Comment: I dont think assigning function to `onRendered` is correct approach, because `onRendered` takes function as callback. So it should be  `Template['override-atPwdForm'].onRendered(function(){})`

Comment: @RamilMuratov - you are absolutely correct. updated the answer.

Comment: Is this defer really necessary? `onRendered` is equivalent of `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Sindis - yes, this defer is necessary. its like meteor is done with template parsing and DOM element creation but they will take few milliseconds to completely become part of container document.